# Can this equation be solved by squaring both sides first?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation can be solved for $x$ by expanding the left side, grouping like terms and then squaring both sides. Can this equation be solved for $x$ by squaring both side first?  If not, why? I can't get past the last step. Thanks
$$\sqrt{a}(d - x) = \sqrt{b}x \Rightarrow$$
$$a(d^{2} - 2dx + x^{2}) = bx^{2} \Rightarrow$$
$$d^{2} - 2dx + x^{2} = x^{2} \frac{b}{a} \Rightarrow$$
$$\frac{d^{2} - 2dx + x^{2}}{x^{2}} = \frac{b}{a}$$

Comment: "The equation can be solved for $x$ by expanding the left side, grouping like terms and then **squaring both sides**." -- To square what? The grouped like terms would be $\sqrt a d = \left(\sqrt a+\sqrt b\right)x$, then division would give $x = \dfrac{\sqrt a d}{\sqrt a + \sqrt b}$.

Comment: @peterwhy Yeah, I don't know what I was thinking of. Maybe all those square roots threw me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yours is a linear equation it doesnt need to be squared.
$$\sqrt{a}(d - x) = \sqrt{b}x \implies (d-x)=x\sqrt{b/a}\implies  x(1+\sqrt{b/a})=d \implies x=\frac{d\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$$